# Hosting a mostly static website on GAE with some php files

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, filepath, app.yaml

I'm hosting a mostly static website on the Google App Engine and have some trouble with setting up my app.yaml it seems. It's either that or my filepath is off. I have seen other posts where mixing static and dynamic content seems to give some trouble so I have decided to set up my files as such:

```
Site (Root Folder)
    app.yaml
    contact (Dynamic page)
        -index.php
    projects (Nothing in here yet but will group dynamic content here)
    README.md
    www (Static files)
        -blog
        -css
        -images
        -index.html
        -js
```

Trying to create link on my homepage which is

```
/www/index.html
```

to my contact page which is

```
/contact/index.php
```

My filepath that should direct you from index.html to index.php is

```
../contact/index.php
```

and below is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
    - url: /
      static_files: www/index.html
      upload: www/index.html
      mime_type: home
      secure: always

    - url: /(.*)
      static_files: www/\1
      upload: www/(.*)
      secure: always
      application_readable: true

    - url: contact/index.php
      script: /contact/index.php
      secure: always
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried several different file paths but haven't been able to get the page to show up at all. When I click on the link that is supposed to take my to contacts page (index.php), I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wildcard catch-all handler is grabbing `contact/index.php` before it can get to its proper handler.  Plus, you are missing the leading slash.  `mimetype: home` is improper.  Try this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /contact/index.php
  script: /contact/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
  secure: always
  application_readable: true
```

Comment: I ended up adding items to the yaml but this worked! I'm so happy aha